# How to Print values associated with single key on next line?

Tags: java, hashmap

## How Output should be:

```
India
```

Karnataka     Belgaum

```
          Bangalore
```

Maharashtra   Pune

```
         Mumbai
```

## How I am getting:

[India]

Karnataka    [Belgaum, Bangalore]

Maharashtra    [Pune, Mumbai]

> ```
>  public static void main(String[] args) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     ArrayList l1= new ArrayList();
>     l1.add("Belgaum");
>     l1.add("Bangalore");
> ```

```
    ArrayList l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    l2.add(""+"India");
    System.out.print("       ");
    System.out.println(l2);

    ArrayList l3= new ArrayList();
    l3.add("Pune");
    l3.add("Mumbai");

    HashMap hashmap = new HashMap();
    hashmap.put("Karnataka", l1);
    hashmap.put("Maharashtra",l3);

    Set s1=hashmap.entrySet();

    Iterator i1=s1.iterator();
    while(i1.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry m1=(Map.Entry)i1.next();
    System.out.println(m1.getKey()+"    "+m1.getValue()+"\n");
    }
}

}
```

Is there any way to get the output as as shown above?

How Can I remove[] associated with values,I know its a Arraylist so java put [] before and after list

Comment: You would have to write some code to print the list in the format you want.

Comment: You're relying on the toString() method implementation of ArrayList. In order to print the list values in a custom way, you have to get the list, iterate over the elements and build the string yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList l1= new ArrayList();
        l1.add("Belgaum");
        l1.add("Bangalore");

        ArrayList l2 = new ArrayList<>();
        l2.add(""+"India");
        System.out.print("       ");
        System.out.println(l2.get(0));

        ArrayList l3= new ArrayList();
        l3.add("Pune");
        l3.add("Mumbai");

        HashMap hashmap = new HashMap();
        hashmap.put("Karnataka", l1);
        hashmap.put("Maharashtra",l3);

        Set s1=hashmap.entrySet();

        Iterator i1=s1.iterator();
        while(i1.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry m1=(Map.Entry)i1.next();
            String tmpStr = m1.getKey().toString();
            ArrayList<String> tmpList = (ArrayList<String>) m1.getValue();
            for (String s : tmpList){
                tmpStr = tmpStr + " " + s;
            }
            System.out.println(tmpStr);
        }
    }
```

I used a couple of different mechanizes like enhanced iterators and building strings so you can see a different approach of what you used, this is a draft and although it works, you can modify it and altered it in multiple ways

my suggestions is to use ArrayList with explicit type e.g

```
ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList()
```

Comment: For longer lists this code is a performance disaster. Consider using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: great!!It worked for me with some modification. critical part here is to use for each loop well.